# HTML/CSS list item has too much space on the left side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an unordered list where the list items are links and when you hover over each link, the background of that list item changes color. I also changed the list-style-type to none which removed the dot next to each item, however, the space where the dot used to be remains. How do I remove this space?

```css
.landing-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50vw;
  background-color: gray;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.landing-dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="landing-dropdown">
  <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
  <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the padding.. with a padding: 0;
also changed list-style-type to list-style: none;

```css
  .landing-dropdown{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50vw;
    background-color: gray;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .landing-dropdown-item:hover{
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="landing-dropdown">
   <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
   <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your CSS:

```
.landing-dropdown {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   list-style-type: none;
}
```

Usually, list tags have some default styling implemented by the browser.
For example when Google Chrome will add these styles to your `<ul>`:

[image: default chrome ul tag styles]

By adding the CSS above, that uses a CSS class instead of the HTML tag, you will have more CSS specificity hence you will override the default styles of the browsers.

An example:

```css
section {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
}


.reset-style {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section>

    <div>A list without margin, padding and list-style-type reset
        <ul class="reset-style">
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>A list with the default styles
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<section>
```

Comment: The issue is still persisting

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to leave the text on the list without any margin or padding to the sides or up and down, however, since **you've requested it** like that hence I am sharing with you a code snippet doing exactly what you've asked. I have changed the background color or the UL tag since I couldn't see the text well on my end but you can def change it back the desired color of your preference.

I certainly hope this helps, pal. Happy coding!

```css
 .landing-dropdown{
     padding: 0;
     position: absolute;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     top: 30px;
     left: 50vw;
     color: #EAECEE;
     background-color: #283747;
     list-style-type: none;
}
 .landing-dropdown-item:hover{
     color: #17202A;
     background-color: #ABB2B9;
}
```

```html
<ul class="landing-dropdown">
   <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
   <li class="landing-dropdown-item"><a>DropDown</a></li>
</ul>
```